# utf-8 error when opening csv file in pandas on mac

Tags: python, pandas, csv, utf-8

I am trying to open a csv file with Japanese characters using utf8 on my mac.

The code that I am using is as follows:

```
foo = pd.read_csv("filename.csv", encoding = 'utf8')
```

However, I have been getting the following error message.

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 0
```

I've tried looking around but a lot of the solutions seem to be for windows/I haven't had any success with other solutions yet.

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your file really has a non-unicode character. A correct encoding for this file strongly depends on its content, but in the most common case, 0x96 can be decoded with CP-1252. So, just try to decode it like following:

```
foo = pd.read_csv("filename.csv", encoding = 'cp1252')
```

If you don't know the original encoding of the file, you can try to detect it with third-party libs such as [chardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet).

I may help you a little bit more if you upload a chunk of the file to reproduce the problem.

Comment: thanks! unfortunately i also tried 'cp1252' so i agree, i think i need to further look into the file to see what is goin gon and find the original coding. appreciate the help!

Comment: @user_seaweed: eventually you can use http://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html : it helps to determine the encodings

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in numbers and export it to csv. You may notice that file is saved without '.csv' extension in the destination folder, that's fine.
Now access the file with < pd.read_csv("filename.csv") >.
Worked for me.

Comment: In other words, you’re relying on Numbers guessing the encoding correctly and re-writing it to a UTF-8 encoded file. While that might work, it also mightn’t, and you’re better off actually knowing the encoding of the file to begin with.